# Can't add QAF BDD Editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, qaf

Can someone please help on how I can add QAF BDD editor plugin in eclipse? The steps in this page https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Installing+QAF+editor+plugins+in+eclipse doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Will you provide details about error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside VPN with proxy make sure that [proxy configured](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm) properly. Make sure that you are able to [access plugin site](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/editor/bdd/eclipse/). If you are not able to access plugin site you need to connect your network team to get it downloaded and install from local disk.