# How to fix "Unable to read repository at https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/editor/bdd/eclipse/content.xml.java.util.NoSuchElementException". exception

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bdd, qaf

I am trying to install QAF BDD from eclipse marketplace. I am using **Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2**. During installation I'm facing an exception like

> **Unable to read repository at**
>   https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/editor/bdd/eclipse/content.xml.java.util.NoSuchElementException.

Is there any updated path for qmetry from which I can install QAF BDD?

I've tried changing different network proxy settings, also by the option **Install new Software**, still not working. If there is anything I am missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is observed when tried to installed plugin inside VPN where access restricted. In such case user from few enterprises install using local site by getting plugin zip from their IT team. Another reason can be [corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486327/cant-add-qaf-bdd-editor-in-eclipse/55539271?r=SearchResults#55539271).